# How to remove Google plus author profile picture from blog search results

Tags: wordpress, google-search, blog, google-plus

I created a company blog and linked it to my Google plus account for the SEO weight, my problem is now the blog has gained popularity and my profile photo is appearing in the search results for the blog.

I have removed the link from my blog to my profile, I have also deleted the blog from the "contributor to" section of my Google plus account.

It has now been nearly a week and the results haven't changed, does anyone know if you are able to remove yourself at all as the feature is currently only a pilot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a caching issue, I would give it another week. Also depends how often you update your blog, cause blogs that are updated frequently will have newer content featured on a search engine or revised content featured on a search engine much more faster then a static site.

Comment: I thought that too although my picture is now appearing in search results for blog posts I created AFTER i removed the link, could it be the Google now associates my profile with the blog and I have to manually request removal?

Comment: You could send a email requesting the removal, or what would be much faster is to replace the Google Plus account with another, create one for your company and associate the blog with the new account and this should lead to a faster update.

Comment: Which one? It's not clear what answer you have accepted. Is it sending an email request? replacing your Google plus page or waiting?

Comment: I can't remember... this was back in August 2012...

Answer (score 3):

**Turn off Blog Association in Google Plus Profile**

I was wondering about this myself and I found a solution simply follow these easy steps:

1. Login to your [**Google Plus**](https://plus.google.com/) **Account**
2. Enter your personal page about you (Click Your **Picture** or **Name**)
3. Once on your personal page click the '**About**' Tab
4. Once revealing the About Tab Contents Click '**Edit Profile**' (Near Top Right)
5. Once editing is enabled check to see if you have your blog in '**Other Profiles**'
6. If you see that your blog is mentioned simply click it and **'confirm delete'**

**Testing the results**

Google users caching on search results so its best clear your cache and cookies, or if using Chrome wack **CTRL** + **SHIFT** + **N** to open a new chrome window that is in **[incognito mode](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464)** (no cache, no cookies and results should be as they should - handy for testing search results when you think Google is caching.)